# How can I access IP address from same sub-net as WAN IP address using DD-WRT?

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

I have a router with DD-WRT v24-sp2 installed and I am having troubles accessing an another IP address that is configured within the same sub-net as my public IP address. My ISP requires to establish WAN connection using DHCP, so both IP and Gateway is assigned automatically. IP address assigned to WAN interface is also a public IP address.

So to illustrate this example:

```
DD-WRT router -> [lan] ip: 192.168.1.1/24
                 [wan] ip: 12.34.56.78/24 (public IP)
```

Now let's assume my neighbour uses same ISP with same configuration and therefore is connected to same public `12.34.56.0/24` network (e.g. with WAN IP address `12.34.56.10`) and exposes some services on that public IP. The problem I'm having is that I cannot access that service or even ping my neighbour public IP from neither my DD-WRT router nor any device connected to this router.

I can access though this service without any issues when I use a different internet connection, so I'm 100% sure this problem persists only behind my DD-WRT router.

My routing table looks as follows:

```
root@DD-WRT:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         12.34.56.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vlan2
12.34.56.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vlan2
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.66.0    192.168.66.2    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.66.2    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
```

Any ideas how to start tackling that?

Comment: Are you shure your WAN is a /24 subnet? Hard to believe the ISP spends 254 valuable IPv4 addresses for one ?NAT?-Router.

Comment: Well, but I believe that's the way it is. I can see it in both DD-WRT WAN Status page as well as in route output provided in question (see 2nd row with address 12.34.56.0 with 255.255.255.0 genmask). I'm by no means a network expert though, so in case I'm missing sth, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert either. I'm writing this because I have a similar setup with my ISP (WAN as a `/24` subnet), with similar routing table. The difference is it works. I can even sniff packets traveling from or to some of my "neighbors" (not all of them though; these with whom I share a hub, I think).

`traceroute` to my "neighbor" shows a single hop as I expected.

In your case it looks like there's no one-hop connection between you and your neighbor or some transparent devices there separate you for some reason. Either way your ISP's config isn't exactly what I would expect according to these DHCP settings you get. There's some peculiarity on the ISP's side. The right thing for ISP to do may be:

- allowing you and your neighbor to communicate with one hop via transparent devices like hubs, switches etc. which will make this a regular subnet; or
- allowing you and your neighbor to communicate with two hops via the gateway.

#### What you can try on your own

This second bullet above doesn't mean you're not allowed at all to communicate with your neighbor via the gateway *now*. You may or may not be allowed, the gateway may be configured either way. The point is: with your current routing table you're not trying to.

The second line of your routing table (`12.34.56.0 …`) tells your router that whenever it needs to send a packet to your neighbor it should send it with the neighbor's IP *and* hardware (MAC) address as a destination. The hardware address is initially unknown so the router broadcasts for it. This never gets to the neighbor and you're stuck.

Try to temporarily delete the second row from the routing table:

```
route del -net 12.34.56.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev vlan2
```

and let the default one act. Every packet from you to your neighbor will be destined to his or her IP but to the hardware address of the gateway (similarly to when you communicate with the outside world). Now it's the gateway job to deliver this packet. It may or may not do this.

In my case, if I delete the proper routing rule, I can still reach my "neighbors"; `traceroute` shows *two* hops, the middle node is my ISP's gateway. The problem is with responses: they are destined directly to my hardware address because of my "neighbor's" *unaltered* routing table. This works for me but it wouldn't work for you. So your neighbor *must* do the same trick with *their* routing table and then it *may* work.

I happen to have admin access to one of my "neighbors". I changed its routing table as well as mine. Then I confirmed with `wireshark` the packets hop via the gateway (using its hardware address) in both directions.

If it works for you and your neighbor then make this change permanent somehow. Of course this is a workaround and it would be better if your ISP changed the configuration.